# Can not decode bitmap Image returns null

Tags: android, bitmap

I have camera app that clicks picture and saves it on sd card 
and when I decode that it gives null bitmap here is the code

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"FacePhoto.jpg");
```

I have checked in ddms the Facephoto file exists on sd card

what can be problem here that I get "null" bitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/FacePhoto.jpg"`

use '/filename' instead of just 'filename'.

If this doesn't work try using

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/FacePhoto.jpg"`

The point to note is to use absolute path instead of relative.

Also see if filename is correctly spelled in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with your image path just check like this

```
File rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(rootDir + "/FacePhoto.jpg");

if (file.exists())
{
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);

}
else
{
   System.out.println("File Not Exists. Check the path!!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a slash, change the code as follows.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/FacePhoto.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Now on activity result you have to use like this.

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
                final File file = getTempFile();

                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            selPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                            final String selectedImagePath = file
                                    .getAbsolutePath();
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory
                                    .decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                            selPath = selectedImagePath;

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(IMAGENOTLOADED);
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
```

getTempFile method is like this

```
private File getTempFile() {
    final File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            getPackageName());
    if (!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdir();
    }
    return new File(path, fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following :

```
     FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/Pics/Image.png"); 
            BufferedInputStream bif = new BufferedInputStream(instream); 
            byteImage1 = new byte[bif.available()]; 
            bif.read(byteImage1); 
             BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage1, 0, byteImage1.length);
```